# SQL INSERT data based on a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have two tables in a database, `Products` and `ProductKeys`.

`Products` columns:

- `ProductID` (PK)
- `ProductName`

`ProductKeys` columns:

- `ID` (PK)
- `ProductKey`
- `ProductID` (FK)
- `Price`

I am trying to insert a new `ProductKey`.

Let's say I have a product with `ProductID = 1` and `ProductName = 'test'`

```
Insert into ProductKeys(ProductKey, ProductID, Price)
    select 'testkey', 1, 4
```

This of course works. But what if I want to insert a new `ProductKey` based on a product name and the `ProductID` to be set automatically based on the `ProductName`.

I hope you understand my issue. Thank you in advance people! Cheers.

EDIT: To insert in that table i must provide all fields a value , but what if I do not know the value of the ProductID and I know the ProductName, so I can insert a ProductKey based on a ProductName not a ProductID.

Sorry for the mess guys , new to SQL.

Comment: pls explain with some example

Comment: I'm assuming this is [tag:sql-server]?  Please tag your question appropriately.  Additionally the [tag:c#] tag is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select data to insert based on a table's data as so:

```
Insert into ProductKeys(ProductKey , ProductID , Price)
select p.productName, p.productId, 1 -- whatever your price is
from products p
where p.productName = 'testkey'
```

> Sir, can I ask you , can this be extended? for example! If the ProductName does not exist the command won't work for sure. But if in case when ProductName does not exist ALSO insert a NEW product in Products table with the selected ProductName and also create the ProductKey. Can it be extended with a 'not exist'? Thanks a bunch sir! You already helped me alot!

I don't think you could do this in a single statement - maybe you could use an on before insert trigger, but I think something like that would break down with batch inserts. (but don't quote me on this, never tried it)

You could however break it up into multiple statements like this:

```
declare @productName varchar(50), @productId int, @price int

select 
        @productName = 'someNameThatDoesntExist', 
        @price = 5 -- whatever your price is.

if not exists (     -- check if the product name exists in the products table, if not create it
    select 1 
    from products 
    where productName = @productName
)
    begin
        insert into products (productName)
        select @productName

        select @productId = @@identity
    end
else -- the product already exists in the products table, so lookup its ID
    select @productId = productId
    from products
    where productName = @productName

Insert into ProductKeys(ProductKey , ProductID , Price)
select @productName, @productId, @price
```

Comment: This worked sir! Thanks a bunch! But a little modified. " Insert into ProductKeys (ProductKey , ProductId ,Price) select 'insert_random_key_here' , p.ProductID , 1 from products p where p.productName = 'testkey' " Brilliant! Thanks again!

Comment: Sir, can I ask you , can this be extended? for example! If the ProductName does not exist the command won't work for sure. But  if  in case when ProductName does not exist ALSO insert a NEW product in Products table with the selected ProductName and also create the ProductKey. Can it be extended with a 'not exist'? Thanks a bunch sir! You already helped me alot!

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu updated answer w/ example to create from your recent comment

Comment: I think breaking in two statements will also help! Thanks a bunch sir! AGAIN! <3